# How to limit while loop to display 1 result per an id?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi All I am trying to do a query that has a Join table in the query and there are multiple images by each id, and i am trying to echo 1 result per id, so it only display a result with 1 image. It is displaying all the images at the moment and repeats the result.

E.g. id1- image 1, id1- image2, id1- image3,  id2-image1, etc

I am trying to do id1-image1, id2-image1, id3-image1

I read that i should use Group by but not if that is the correct function to use. 
The help i need is just a quick heads up if "Group by" is the right function or what function i need for this purpose will be good help. Thanks for your time

Here are my code. Thanks again

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

$userid=$_SESSION['id'];
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Listing JOIN listingpic ON 
    (Listing.id = listingpic.listingid ) WHERE Listing.userid = $userid AND Listing.Status='Bird'  ") or die( mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo 'Listing Type:'.$row['type'].'<a href="SpecificListing.html?Listingid='.urlencode($row['listingid']).'">'.$row['listingid'].
   "Click to view the details".'</a>
   <img src="http://test.info/Bootstraptest/image/'.$row['pic'].'"  height="200" width="200">';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Listing JOIN listingpic ON 
(Listing.id = listingpic.listingid)
 WHERE Listing.userid = $userid AND Listing.Status='Bird' group by Listing.user_id ") or die( mysqli_error($con));
```

it is the  only option to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
SELECT listing.row1,listing.row2,listingpic.row1 FROM 
(
select listing.row1, listing.row2 from listing where condition
)listing join listingpic

WHERE Listing.userid = $userid AND Listing.Status='Bird'
```